# Program using ast.literal_eval is too slow

Tags: python-3.x, loops

I tried to transform strings into list using `ast.literal_eval` function for a column in a CSV file. The string is something like this `'['abbb','cddd','cdcdc']'`. For some reason this is a string instead of list, I tried to use `ast.literal_eval` to transform it into a list with components `'abbb'`,`'cddd'` and `'cdcdc'`. The problem is the execution is to slow (there are 1326101 rows to execute). The code I use is this:

```
import pandas as pd
import ast
import sys

user_dataset = pd.read_csv('user.csv')
for x in range(len(user_dataset['friends'])):
    if user_dataset['friends'][x]!=[]:
        """Covert string to list"""
        user_dataset['friends'][x] = ast.literal_eval(user_dataset['friends'][x])
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The title should be Python Programme Too Slow ast.literal_eval. Sorry!

Comment: So this works, it's just slow?  Iterating directly over `user_dataset['friemds']` would probably help some.  Could  you share some sample data?  Maybe `user_dataset.head()`?